# dual boot Ubuntu and windows ThinkPad, installed on partition won't boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, thinkpad

I have successfully installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a partition, originally windows software on a ThinkPad X1 carbon.  So I can use both operating systems, booting to either on powerup.

However it just boots to windows everytime, unless I set the BIOS to boot from the USB.  Is there something I can set in the bios?  I would like to avoid a complete Ubuntu install wiping windows, if possible.

Thanks

Comment: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the summary report ( not post full report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
What model Thinkpad? And are both systems in same boot mode, both UEFI or both BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

If you tell the BIOS to boot from USB it does not boot your installed Ubuntu but the version that is on your USB-stick.

Your problem is that the Windows-Bootloader is started before GRUB and Windows does not allow any other OS to be booted. What you need to do is prioritize GRUB. There are plenty of guides online, e.g. [this one](https://www.lifewire.com/fix-uefi-bootloader-issues-when-dual-booting-2200655).